# SASS normal class and nested class to have same attribute

Tags: css, sass

I'm wanting a nested class and a normal class to use the same attributes. For example...

```
.menu-container ul li.run a,
body[data-primary-tags*='run'] {
    .article-overview-header,
    .article-detail-header-strip,
    .article-detail-sub-header {
        background-color: $run;
    }   
}
```

Obviously this won't work but is there a way to have `li.run a` and the nested class to have the same background-color?

Comment: why do you say "this won't work"? If you set the `$run` variable to "red" for example, you get: `.menu-container ul li.run a .article-overview-header,
.menu-container ul li.run a .article-detail-header-strip,
.menu-container ul li.run a .article-detail-sub-header,
body[data-primary-tags*='run'] .article-overview-header,
body[data-primary-tags*='run'] .article-detail-header-strip,
body[data-primary-tags*='run'] .article-detail-sub-header {
  background-color: red;
}` What CSS you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Using SASS `@extend` you could do something like this:

```
.my-special-class
    background-color: $run

.menu-container ul li.run a,
body[data-primary-tags*='run']
    @extend .my-special-class

    .article-overview-header,
    .article-detail-header-strip,
    .article-detail-sub-header
        @extend .my-special-class
```

To achieve that in pure CSS you should make parent class background color of your choice, and let nested class have inherit values. Although they would need to be first-generation children to inherit proper value.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think is probably the only option right now.